# Hibernate Oracle Stored Procedure Missing Expression Exception

Tags: hibernate, parameters, oracle11g, output, expression

I am using Java 1.7, Hibernate 4 with annotations instead of xml mapping, Oracle 11G.
I have this Oracle SP:

```
PROCEDURE SP_NAME (PI_USERID    IN     VARCHAR2,
                   PO_USERLIST  OUT    SYS_REFCURSOR)
   IS
   BEGIN
      OPEN PO_USERLIST FOR
           SELECT USERID, NAME
           FROM SC_SCRCRDA.GSCRSCRCT0045
           WHERE USERID = TO_NUMBER (PI_USERID)
      COMMIT;
   END;
```

When I call it from Java using Hibernate it says: ORA-00936 Missing Expression Exception. It is thrown in bold last line.
Here is the call:

```
public Users obtenerUsuario(String usuarioId) throws Exception {
    Session session = UtilsHelper.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    List<Object[]> tuples=new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    Query query = session.createSQLQuery("CALL PACKAGE.NAME(:userId,:out)");
    query = query.setParameter("userId", usuarioId);
    query= query.setParameterList("out", tuples);

    **List<Object[]> tuples1= (List<Object[]>) query.list();**
    ...
}
```

Do you know why this exception is thrown?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Because the tuples is an empty list.

The exception appears when adding an empty list as a query parameter list. Not sure why this happens - doesn't seem to happen all the time ...

```
query= query.setParameterList("out", tuples);
```